# Can't return completedsuccesfull task in .net core

Tags: .net-core, task

Hi I wrote the following code:

```
  private bool GetIsCompleted()
  {
        return Email.SendMessageAsync().IsCompletedSuccessfully;
  }
   [HttpPost]
    public  ViewResult CheckOut(Order order)
    {
        if (Cart.Lines.Count() == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("","Your Cart is empty!");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            order.CartLines = Cart.Lines;
            order.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
            order.TotalPrice = Cart.ComputeTotalValue();
            if (Repository.SaveOrder(order))
            {
                if (User.Identity.Name != null)
                {
                    Email.SetMessageBody(order.OrderID);

                    if (GetIsCompleted())
                    {
                        Cart.Clear();
                        return View("Completed");
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewBag.Error = "An error Occured while sending you an email with the order details.";
            return View(new Order());
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "An error Occured while trying to save your order. Please try again!";
            return View(new Order());
        }             
    }

 public async Task SendMessageAsync()
    {
        this.Message = new MailMessage(this.MailFrom.ToString(), this.MailTo.ToString(), this.GetSubject(), this.GetMessageBody());
        //Message.Dispose();

        try
        {
            await this.Client.SendMailAsync(this.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("The Email couldn't send to the recipient");
        }
    }
```

I get

> An error Occured while sending you an email with the order details.

in the View. I want GetIsCompleted() to return true to proceed the code. It is developed under .net core. I do not understand why IsCompletedSuccessfully() does not return true; Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The current flow of your code is this:

1. Start sending the e-mail.
2. Check if it is completed successfully, decide that it hasn't and return failure.
3. The e-mail completes sending.

You're awaiting the actual `SendMailAsync(..)` method, and that's great, but nothing awaits `SendMessageAsync(...)` so it immediately returns the incomplete task to the caller. Because there isn't enough time between starting to send the e-mail and checking if the task completed, the status will be false.

You need to use async all the way up. Change your method definition to be async:

```
public async Task<ViewResult> CheckOut(Order order)
```

Replace this code:

```
if (GetIsCompleted())
{
    Cart.Clear();
    return View("Completed");
}
```

with this:

```
try
{
    await Email.SendMessageAsync();
    Cart.Clear();
    return View("Completed");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle exception
}
```

It's worth noting that you'll only ever get an exception if the call to `new MailMessage(...)` fails because your try/catch block in `SendMessageAsync` is swallowing all other exceptions.